# Did someone using a private jet tell Americans their expectations are too high?

Tags: politics, quotes, climate-change

From [twitter](https://twitter.com/lachlan/status/557953943356317696), a tweet that's going viral, including among climate change skeptics (action against climate change is being discussed at Davos):

> The cognitive dissonance in the first & last sentences of this excerpt
>   is something to behold
>   http://www.bloomberg.com/news/print/2015-01-21/billionaire-greene-goes-long-on-u-s-while-bemoaning-jobs-crisis.html
>   …

Quoted section (emphasis added myself):

> “**America’s lifestyle expectations are far too high and need to be
>   adjusted so we have less things and a smaller, better existence**,”
>   Greene said in an interview today at the World Economic Forum in
>   Davos, Switzerland. “We need to reinvent our whole system of life.”
>
> The 60-year-old founder of Coral Gables, Florida-based Florida
>   Sunshine Investments said his biggest fund was up more than 20 percent
>   last year with bets on Apple Inc. (AAPL), Google Inc. (GOOG), bank
>   stocks and mortgage-backed securities.
>
> “I’m remarkably long for my level of pessimism,” he said. “Our economy
>   is in deep trouble. We need to be honest with ourselves. We’ve had a
>   realistic level of job destruction, and those jobs aren’t coming
>   back.”
>
> **Greene, who flew his wife, children and two nannies on a private jet
>   plane to Davos for the week**, said he’s planning a conference in Palm
>   Beach,

Wikipedia's article on [Jeff Greene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeff_Greene) indicates that he's a billionaire, so he can afford a private jet plane, and that he has a luxury yacht, which means that he's likely to own and use a private jet plane. It also indicates that he's politically active.

The main thing I'm skeptical about is whether the first sentence is incorrect and/or taken out of context. The Bloomberg article doesn't link to a transcript of the interview in question.

Comment: He may have been saying that their lifestyle expectations are unrealistic for their pay grade. Unskilled workers on minimum wage can't, for instance, expect brand-new iPhones as soon as new ones come out. People end up taking out loan after loan to fund an unsustainable quality of life. That's probably what he's referring to.

Comment: While Mr. Greene may be a billionaire, that has little to do with owning a private plane. There are many people whose net worth is orders of magnitude less than that, and own private planes of varying sizes. (My uncle, for example, although his plane is too small to fit his four sons plus luggage now that they're teenagers.)

Comment: I don't see what's so surprising about it. Rich people really are that out of touch, and people in general are quick to believe that they deserve everything they have but everyone else doesn't.

Comment: What's the basis for being skeptical of the claim?

Comment: This has been [reported in multiple reliable news outlets](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=jeff+greene+davos+jet&spell=1). If you don't accept those sources, what sources are you going to accept?

Comment: What does this claim have to do with climate change?  PointlessSpike's comment above seems to be accurate, and DJClayworth points to sources verifying the statement.  Perhaps the question should be whether the comment has anything to do with climate change, as some climate change deniers are apparently claiming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Billionaire Says Bloomberg Fabricated His Quote About Americans Needing To Have A 'Smaller Existence'](http://www.businessinsider.com/jeff-greene-walksback-davos-quote-2015-1):

> Greene said that he "was completely misquoted," not misunderstood. He also said that the comments were made in a "busy, noisy room" and "maybe [Matthew G. Miller] didn't hear me."
>
> A rep for Bloomberg News says that the company stands by its reporting.

Comment: So what did he actually say?

Comment: @DonielF i doubt this site is for primary sources :)